# Not getting the Device Token on iPhone iOS 5.1 Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: iphone, ios5, device, token

Like many i struggle with Push notifications.
Now, I got almost everything working. I have the certificates, keys and all in place. I even ran it the first time and got the famous alert box asking me if I want to allow push notifications and clicked OK.
But I never, ever got the printout of the Device Token.
I put a break point in the method below, but never stops there.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWith:DeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For getting device token use

> ```
>  (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWith:DeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
>  {
>  NSString *str = [deviceToken description]; 
>  NSLog(@"%@", str); 
>  }
> ```

Comment: Hey Challenger.

Thanks, but i don't even get into this method. I've put a break point there, but it never gets there.

Comment: This function will not be called in simulator, It will be called only on real device

Comment: OK, so where can I see the printout then? on the device logs in the organizer?

Comment: it will be printed on console if you NSLog the device token

Comment: try this blog http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);`

I had this problem but this code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app in the simulator, the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method will be called as push notifications are not supported in the simulator.